# A formula for a number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say that you are selecting three numbers in the range $[1,n]$.

What formula easily determines the number of combinations where one of the possible numbers (*n* for example) is selected exactly once?
The order of the numbers matters.  ${1,1,2}$ is distinct and different from ${1,2,1}$.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: It does not. { 1, 1, 2 } is distinct from { 1, 2, 1 }

Comment: Well then it **does** matter!!!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that mistake while I was editing the post...oops

Answer (score 1):

We need to select its $2$ companions. If they are distinct they can be chosen in $\binom{n-1}{2}$ ways. If they are identical they can be selected in $n-1$ ways. Add, and simplify.

Note that we get a different answer if we are counting sequences ("words") of length $3$.

Answer (score 0):

It's $3(n-1)^2$. $(n-1)^2$ ways to chose the two arbitrary digits and $3$ ways to place the non-arbitrary digit between them ($a**, *a*, **a$)

Answer (score 0):

Partition your three numbers accordingly: 
$$n_1, n_2, n_3$$
The number of ways you could get a number appearing once in the first position is:
$$(1)(n-1)(n-1)$$

Since there are three different positions, the same logic applies; since multiplication is commutative, we essentially multiply $(1)(n-1)(n-1)$ by $3$ to get:

$$3(n-1)^2.$$